# Grabbing microdata attribute in excel

Tags: excel, vba, html-parsing

I want to grab the itemprop microdata from a website and put each one into a cell in an excel sheet.

```
<li>Item Num: <span itemprop="productID">123ABC-200</span>
        </li>
<li>ManufacturerNum: <span itemprop="model">ABC123</span>
        </li>
```

I'm storing the addresses to scrape within a column and I'm trying to open up IE, navigate to the site, grab the data, and throw it into another cell.

```
Sub scrape()

Dim i As Integer
lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
Set wb = CreateObject("internetExplorer.Application")
sURL = Cells(i, 1)

wb.navigate sURL
wb.Visible = True

While wb.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend

'HTML document
Set doc = wb.document

Cells(i, 2) = doc.Title

On Error GoTo err_clear

Dim el As Object
elem = doc.GetElementsByTagName("span")
atts = elem.getAttribute("itemprop")

For Each el In atts
    Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value & ", " & el.innerText
Next el

err_clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If
wb.Quit
Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 3)).Columns.AutoFit
Next i

End Sub
```

I'm getting back nothing. If I just search for spans, I can pull them all in. I haven't successfully pulled in any attributes from any html element.